# Can somebody provide a standard test to measure ones working memory & short term memory

Tags: memory, test

I suffer from memory problem but find it difficult to undrstand whether it is more belief based or real, need a standard test to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

It might be difficult to distinguish between belief-based and actual memory difficulties, especially in a self-administered test. The most objective measure would be a computerised assessment, e.g. the Automatic Working Memory Assessment, which contains measures of short-term and working memory in the verbal and spatial domain [1]. Some commonly used assessments of these constructs are [2]:

**Verbal short-term memory**: digit span, running span
**Verbal working memory**: backward digit span, n-back span
**Spatial short-term memory**: dot matrix, forward Corsi block task
**Spatial working memory**: backward Corsi block task

[1] http://doi.org/10.1080/01443410802243828
[2] http://doi.org/10.1038/nrn1201